# Creating a title page

Tags: titles

[image]

How can I create such a frame? What I did s as follows:

Note: I use overleaf

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}



\begin{document}

        %  \includegraphics[width=.75\textwidth]{odtu-lang-en}\\
    {\large {\textcolor{red}{MIDDLE EAST TECHNICAL UNIVERSITY}}%

    \hfill Ankara, Turkey
}



 
\end{document}
```

what I obtain is this

[image]

Comment: Looks like there are plenty of packages which you can discard for this example / problem. (Please do so.)

Comment: please can you help me to construct this frame? It is very difficult for me. @MS-SPO

Comment: @MS-SPO I delete unnecessary packages. But nothing changes. Also I cannot add these lines.

Comment: Could it be that your university / department offers a Latex template as part of a corporate design?

Comment: No, unfortunately:( I write mathematical formulas or article in latex. But I don't know create such a frame. @infinitezero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two separate solution approaches:

- Use all-uppercase letters for the two long strings
- Use `\large` small-caps letters for these strings

As the following screenshot shows, the second approach is marginally more refined, mainly because of the improved kerning between the letters.

I would also load the `xurl` and `hyperref` packages to ensure that the URL string acts as a proper hyperlink.

[image]

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

% Version A: uppercase lettering
\noindent
\textcolor{red}{MIDDLE EAST TECHNICAL UNIVERSITY}
\hfill
Ankara, Turkey%
\smallskip
\hrule
\medskip
\hfill\textcolor{ForestGreen}{INSTITUTE OF APPLIED MATHEMATICS}

\hfill\url{http://iam.metu.edu.tr}%
\smallskip
\hrule


\bigskip\bigskip

% Version B: large/smallcaps lettering
\noindent
\textcolor{red}{\large\scshape middle east technical university}
\hfill
Ankara, Turkey%
\smallskip
\hrule
\medskip
\hfill\textcolor{ForestGreen}{\large\scshape institute of applied mathematics}

\hfill\url{http://iam.metu.edu.tr}%
\smallskip
\hrule

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much !!! you are very helpful. Thanks a lot! If you mind, can you help me to create rest of the paper(I added)? I know how to write article or mathematical expression, But it is very difficult to create such a title page. Can you help me please ? I need so much.

Comment: @1190 - Please don't ask new questions by editing an existing posting, as doing so creates rather unstable moving targets. Instead, do please post a new query to ask new questions.

Comment: yes, I can ask at new post :)

Comment: Dear Mico, I post new question. How can I create such a title page? I will be happy, if you share your coding knowledge:) Thanks a lot https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/649954/creating-a-title-page-on-overleaf

Comment: Dear Mico, can you help me please? I need too much :(

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do it, which is a bit the way you'd do it in `TeX`, i.e. without all those nice macros from Latex. Alternatives are e.g. using `tables`.

[image: header]

In the beginning I define your color green. Next I introduce 4 **variables** using `\newcommand`, which kind of simplifies the code to use later, and simplifies manipulating appearance. They are basically constructed like this:

- they contain the text to be displayed
- next they manipulate the font using `\large` and `\scshape` (small caps)
- finally some get some `\color`
- later it turned out that most have to end with `\par` to avoid a nasty blank at the end

I used the small caps and also some variations in writing more for demonstration purposes. You could also type all in caps instead and remove the `\scshape`  from the 2 macros. // It's worth noticing the double braces `{{ .. }}` . First pair is needed to define the macro. Second pair makes the changes local, i.e. reverts fonts to "normal" once the macro was expanded.

Now the TeX-ish typesetting.

First line removes the indenting of the first paragraph. It outputs **uni** and **city** and uses `\hfill`, which simply drives both text fragments as much appart as possible, just like a spring would do.

Next `\medskip` and `\hrule` try to mimick vertical white space and of course the horizontal line.

Finally, **inst** and **web** are output, and this time driven from the left to its outmost right positions by a starting `\hfill`.

P.S.: Followed Mico's advice and replaced `\sc` by `\scshape`, and `\tt` by `\ttfamily`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{green}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}% your green

% constants
\newcommand\uni[0]{{\large \scshape \color{red} Middle East Technical University}}
\newcommand\inst[0]{{\large \scshape \color{green} Institute of applied mathematics\par}}
\newcommand\city[0]{Ankara, Turkey\par}
\newcommand\web[0]{{\large \ttfamily http://iam.metu.edu.tr\par}}


\begin{document}

    \parindent=0pt\uni{}\hfill\city{}
    \medskip
    \hrule
    \medskip
    \hfill\inst{}\par
    \hfill\web{}
    \medskip
    \hrule

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. However, it's not a good idea to use the plain-TeX command `\sc` and `\tt` in a LaTeX document, as these commands are no longer defined in the LaTeX kernel and are not supported by some important document classes. Do use `\scshape` and `\ttfamily` instead.

Comment: you are very helpful. Thanks a lot! If you mind, can you help me to create rest of the paper(I added)? I know how to write article or mathematical expression, But it is very difficult to create such a title page. Can you help me please ? I need so much.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: I also post as a new question. I you mind, you can post your answer. I will be very very glad. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/649954/creating-a-title-page-on-overleaf

Comment: Wrt titlepage I start to exceed my current limitations ... However, have a look at wikibooks https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation , and the documentation of package titlepages at ctan with lots of examples https://ctan.org/pkg/titlepages . These two sources should help you along. // (It may also be an idea to check the categories on ctan, e.g. this one: https://ctan.org/topic/titlepage .)

Comment: I know, I searched, and I tried, but I create them on separate pages. I really don't know how to do @MS-SPO

Answer (score 3):

I have simplified your MWE, among other things many unneeded packages for your problem.

```
% ankaraprob.tex  SE 649949

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


    {\large {MIDDLE EAST TECHNICAL UNIVERSITY}}
%
    \hfill Ankara, Turkey % \mbox{}
%}

    \rule{0.96\textwidth}{1mm}

    \mbox{} \hfill INSTITUTE OF ...

    \mbox{} \hfill \verb!http://...!

    \rule{0.96\textwidth}{1mm}


    And more text after this.

   \end{document}
```

You may want to change some of the lengths to suit your documentstyle better.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. It work well. Can you help me to form the rest of the paper if you mind. I really need. Thank you. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/649954/creating-a-title-page-on-overleaf?noredirect=1#comment1619858_649954